# Output XMLWriter to XML file. Select SQL and save to XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml, c#-4.0

I have an sql query, selects some data from a 2 table.I get these datas from the table. I want create a xml file from the data. 
My program code:

```
        string sConnectionString;
        sConnectionString = "Data Source=NAMESERWER;Initial Catalog=BAZA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user; Password=password;";
        SqlConnection objConn
        = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        objConn.Open();


        SqlDataAdapter faktura = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  [t0].[Faktura] as 'InvoiceNumber', [t0].[FATrN_Data2] as 'Date', [t0].[FATrN_Data3] as 'InvoiceIssueDate',  DATEADD(DD, 90, [t0].[FATrN_Data3]) as 'InvoiceDueDate', '90' as 'PaymentTerms', 'I' as 'PaymentTermsReferenceDate' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);

        SqlDataAdapter paymentmethod1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  'P' as 'CODE', 'Przelew' as 'Description' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);




        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Invoice");
        faktura.Fill(ds, "InvoiceHeader");

       paymentmethod1.Fill(ds, "PaymentMethod");


        XDocument doc1 = new XDocument(
new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null));


        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        ds.WriteXml(@"c:\test.xml");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        objConn.Close();

    }
```

the program code creates a file XML c:\test.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Invoice>
  <InvoiceHeader>
    <InvoiceNumber>(S)FS-551/03/2017</InvoiceNumber>
    <Date>2017-03-31T00:00:00+02:00</Date>
    <InvoiceIssueDate>2017-03-30T00:00:00+02:00</InvoiceIssueDate>
    <InvoiceDueDate>2017-06-28T00:00:00+02:00</InvoiceDueDate>
    <PaymentTerms>90</PaymentTerms>
    <PaymentTermsReferenceDate>I</PaymentTermsReferenceDate>
  </InvoiceHeader>
  <PaymentMethod>
    <CODE>P</CODE>
    <Description>Przelew</Description>
  </PaymentMethod>
</Invoice>
```

I would like the file XML to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Invoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <InvoiceHeader>
    <InvoiceNumber>FSE-551/03/2017</InvoiceNumber>
    <Date>2018-03-31</Date>
    <InvoiceIssueDate>2017-03-30</InvoiceIssueDate>
    <InvoiceDueDate>2017-06-28</InvoiceDueDate>
    <PaymentTerms>30</PaymentTerms>
    <PaymentTermsReferenceDate>I</PaymentTermsReferenceDate>
    <PaymentMethod>
      <Code>P</Code>
      <Description>Transfer</Description>
    </PaymentMethod>
  </InvoiceHeader>
  </Invoice>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sConnectionString;
            sConnectionString = "Data Source=NAMESERWER;Initial Catalog=BAZA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user; Password=password;";
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
            objConn.Open();


            SqlDataAdapter faktura = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  [t0].[Faktura] as 'InvoiceNumber', [t0].[FATrN_Data2] as 'Date', [t0].[FATrN_Data3] as 'InvoiceIssueDate',  DATEADD(DD, 90, [t0].[FATrN_Data3]) as 'InvoiceDueDate', '90' as 'PaymentTerms', 'I' as 'PaymentTermsReferenceDate' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);

            SqlDataAdapter paymentmethod1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  'P' as 'CODE', 'Przelew' as 'Description' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);


            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Invoice");
            faktura.Fill(ds, "InvoiceHeader");

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            ds.WriteXml(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);

            XElement invoice = doc.Element("Invoice");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("PaymentMethod");
            paymentmethod1.Fill(dt);

            stream = new MemoryStream();
            dt.WriteXml(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            XElement paymentMethod = XElement.Load(stream);

            invoice.Add(paymentMethod);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@jdweng

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string sConnectionString;
            sConnectionString = "Data Source=SERWER;Initial Catalog=baza;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user; Password=pass;";
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
            objConn.Open();


            SqlDataAdapter faktura = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  [t0].[Faktura] as 'InvoiceNumber', [t0].[FATrN_Data2] as 'Date', [t0].[FATrN_Data3] as 'InvoiceIssueDate',  DATEADD(DD, 90, [t0].[FATrN_Data3]) as 'InvoiceDueDate', '90' as 'PaymentTerms', 'I' as 'PaymentTermsReferenceDate' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);

            SqlDataAdapter paymentmethod1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  'P' as 'CODE', 'Przelew' as 'Description' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);


            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Invoice");
            faktura.Fill(ds, "InvoiceHeader");

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            ds.WriteXml(@"c:\test1.xml");
            stream.Position = 0;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\test1.xml");

            XElement invoice = doc.Element("Invoice");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("PaymentMethod");
            paymentmethod1.Fill(dt);

            stream = new MemoryStream();
            dt.WriteXml(@"c:\test1.xml");
            stream.Position = 0;
            XElement paymentMethod = XElement.Load(@"c:\test1.xml");

            invoice.Add(paymentMethod);
        }
    }
}
```

xml now looks like this :(:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <PaymentMethod>
    <CODE>P</CODE>
    <Description>Przelew</Description>
  </PaymentMethod>
</DocumentElement>
```

Comment: Looks like something changed from original posting.  Where did "DocumentElement" come from?

Answer (score 0):

This is orginal code

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string sConnectionString;
            sConnectionString = "Data Source=SERWER;Initial Catalog=baza;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user; Password=pass;";
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
            objConn.Open();


            SqlDataAdapter faktura = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  [t0].[Faktura] as 'InvoiceNumber', [t0].[FATrN_Data2] as 'Date', [t0].[FATrN_Data3] as 'InvoiceIssueDate',  DATEADD(DD, 90, [t0].[FATrN_Data3]) as 'InvoiceDueDate', '90' as 'PaymentTerms', 'I' as 'PaymentTermsReferenceDate' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);

            SqlDataAdapter paymentmethod1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  'P' as 'CODE', 'Przelew' as 'Description' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);


            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Invoice");
            faktura.Fill(ds, "InvoiceHeader");

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            ds.WriteXml(@"c:\test1.xml");
            stream.Position = 0;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\test1.xml");

            XElement invoice = doc.Element("Invoice");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("PaymentMethod");
            paymentmethod1.Fill(dt);

            stream = new MemoryStream();
            dt.WriteXml(@"c:\test1.xml");
            stream.Position = 0;
            XElement paymentMethod = XElement.Load(@"c:\test1.xml");

            invoice.Add(paymentMethod);
        }
    }
}
```